# pointer movement what is difference between cs[1], and *cs++

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to understand how the pointers are moving.
Following is the program and I am aware that
if

```
int cs={1,2,3};
```

then  `cs` points to `cs[0]`
what I am not clear is what is *cs pointing to.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int *arrptr1 = array;
        int *arrptr = array;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(int); i++) {
                printf("%d, %d, %d\n", array[i], *arrptr1++, *arrptr + i);
        }
}
```

the output of above program is

```
1, 1, 1
2, 2, 2
3, 3, 3
4, 4, 4
5, 5, 5
```

then my understanding `*arrptr` should increase the value stored at

```
*arrptr
```

should get incremented by 1.
Where as what I observe is the pointer is moving to next location.So just want to know what is wrong in my understanding?

**UPDATE**
As per the replies below I understand that

```
print("%d", *arrptr1++);
```

in such a statement evaluation of operators is from right to left.
Hence in `*arrptr1++`  the `++` will get evaluated first and then `arrptr` and then `*`
So to confirm the same I wrote another program

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int array[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
        int *q1 = array;
        printf("q1 = %p\n",q1);
      printf("*q1++ = %d\n",*q1++);
        printf("q1 = %p\n",q1);
      printf("*q1++ = %d\n",*q1);
}
```

The output of above program is different than the expected operator precedence by above logic.
The output  I got is

```
q1 = 0x7ffffcff02e0
*q1++ = 10
q1 = 0x7ffffcff02e4
*q1++ = 20
```

So I was expecting in the 2nd line of output instead of `*q1++ = 10` following `*q1++ = 20`
so did the operator precedence not happened right to left?

Comment: does it matter that you are using post-increment?

Comment: Do you mean `int *cs = { /* ...` or `int cs[] = { /* ...` ?

Comment: Try that again using random numbers for the array... You should see a pattern for the last of the numbers.

Comment: Simply try to change your array to {10,20,30,40,50}. May be you will get the difference.

Comment: @Manoj R that was a great suggestion and I got a different output.+ 1 for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that `*arrptr1++` is interpreted as `*(arrptr1++)`, which means that the pointer to the array is increased by one each time in the loop, and hence it will point to the same element as `array[i]`. `*arrptr + i` on the other hand is interpreted as "the *value* of the array element pointed to by `arrptr` plus the integer `i`". In this loop it means it will display the same thing as `array[i]`, but it is not pointing at the same element (`arrptr` is always pointing to the first element in your array). If you change the values in the array to something more random, it should be obvious when you run the program again.

Answer (score 2):

`*arrptr1++` is parsed as `*(arrptr1++)`, not `(*arrptr1)++`.

Comment: ... and so the `printf` line has _undefined behavior_.

Comment: @Charles Bailley I have added an update as per your comment.Is that behavor in second program due to undefined printf behavior can you confirm it?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you use dereference operator * and pre-increment(pre-decrement) or post-increment(post-decrement) operator on a variable simultaneously ,the order of operation is from right to left (if parenthesis are not used).

What you want to do is
`(*arrptr)++`

because of higher precedence of (), it will force the compiler to first access the element pointed to by arrptr and then increment its value.
When you do this `*arrptr++` , as I've said it first operates rightmost operator (i.e. ++)
and then the dereference operator.
If you will write

EDITED (only the comment): `*++arrptr // increment the pointer then access`

it will first advance the pointer and then access the value
stored in the address now pointed to by arrptr.
One more thing,The comma used for separation of function argument is not the comma operator so the order of evaluation of the arguments is undefined. (already been told)

Comment: I am confused a bit for the *arrptr+i thing how does operator precedence here works?

Comment: please see the update section of my question.I have written a new program to understand what you mentioned is actually happening but that does not seems to be exactly the case.Can you comment on why is there deviation.

Comment: In your update ,*q1++ has post-increment operator so the pointer will be incremented and the value referenced will be the one previously pointed to by the pointer, not the value now pointed to by the pointer.*++q1(pre-increment) in printf  will make it print 20.

Comment: Now your program has no undefined behavior in the printf statements.
Binary + operator has lower precedence than * so it will dereference pointer and then add i into the value.Follow K&R for operator precedence list.

Answer (score 0):

cs = &cs[0] ( cs is equal to the address of cs sub 0) ; *cs = cs[0] (cs pointer is equal to cs sub 0) ; You should remember that *'s hide the [].

```
    // here is a print function with a pointer
    int foo[5] = { 2, 9, 1, 3, 6};
    int *walker, count;

    walker = foo;

    for (count = 0; count < 5; walker++, count++)
        printf("Array[%d]: %d\n", count, *walker);
```

Recap: walker is equal to &foo[0], so when you increment walker (eg. walker++) you're moving the pointer to the next address which is foo[1]. And when we are printing the value we can't say ..., walker); since walker( &foo[whatever] ) is pointing to an address, we need to dereference the pointer to get the value. Again, the most important thing to remember

```
array = &array[0] AND *array = array[0]
```

Comment: I understood your point. I have updated my question now please have a look at the update section and let me know if you find some thing wrong in my logic.

Comment: @Registered User- I'm not sure what you're trying to do in that update section. Also, I think the "right to left" thing is confusing you. When you see these operators *, ++, --, +, etc.. You can just look up the Operator Precedence table to see what is going to happen first.

Comment: @Registered User-I think you need to focus on how the pointers work before you worry about the precedence issue, which will just come to you easily later. You should start making test code that will have pointer walk arrays ( Strings too! ). Then move to 2D integer arrays ( which you will find that using indices is much simpler, which in this case simplicity wins ), then of course you can test with 2D ragged array( strings)  which would be an array of pointers to strings